# How not to display already booked dates in the form using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

How can you not display the booked time when you choose a date? For example, after we selected a date and opened the time list, only free time was displayed. To insert data into mysql, I used the following code: `

```
     function insert ($table, $params){
             global $pdo;
             $i = 0;
             $coll = '';
             $mask = '';
             foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                 if ($i === 0){
                     $coll = $coll . "$key";
                     $mask = $mask . "'" . "$value" . "'";
                 }else{
                      $coll = $coll . ", $key";
                     $mask = $mask . ", '" . "$value" . "'";
                 }
                 $i++;
             }
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($coll) VALUES ($mask)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
    $query->execute();
    dbCheckError($query);
 }


    if (isset ($_POST['fname'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $review = $_POST['review'];
    
        $post = [
        'fio' => $fname,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'type' => $type,
        'date' => $date,
        'time' => $time,
        'description' => $review
        ];
    
    insert ('vet_center.applicat', $post);
    }
```

In HTML, the markup for time and date is presented as:

```
<input type="date" id="appointment" name="date" max="2023-12-31" min="2022-05-08">

              <label for="time">Время</label>
              <select id="time" name="time">
             <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
             <option value="10:00:00">10:00</option>
             <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
             <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
             <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
             <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
             <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
             <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
             <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
           </select>
```

Form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS5xa.png)

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection attack because of the POST variables being used directly in the SQL.

Comment: How is the `time` select menu generated? How is a `time` recorded as `taken` or `free` in the db?

Comment: I'm just getting to know php, so I try to do simple things. The busy time is recorded in sql, the time can be selected simply from the list created using html.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do exactly

Comment: There is a form (I added a picture to the description) it is necessary that after selecting the desired date and opening the time selection field, only free time is displayed

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article.

Comment: To avoid displaying certain times if they have already been taken you need to generate the menu with PHP- query the db to find all possible times with their `busy time` status - if they are allocated as busy do not print to the page.